# Highcharts-convert missing labels

Tags: highcharts-convert

I have the same code, running the same highcharts-convert.js and phantomjs on two servers. One produces perfect charts images the other is missing all labels. Does anyone know why or where to start looking?

Comment: Probably you are missing the reference. just check whether dependencies are loaded on the network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely missing font packages on the failing host.  Highcharts-convert uses the fonts available to it, but will silently skip labels if there aren't any available.  I had this happen and running

```
sudo yum install dejavu-fonts-common dejavu-sans-fonts dejavu-serif-fonts libXfont xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

fixed it.  I don't yet know what subset of those packages would have been sufficient, but I suspect "libXfont xorg-x11-fonts-Type1" would do it.

Comment: Thank you for the great solution!
You were right, only libXfont xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 was required.